# Placeholder text color in TextField

Tags: swift, textfield, swiftui

Is it possible to change the placeholder text color in `SwiftUI.TextField`?

Comment: Hey, I have added a `CustomTextField` to make *placeholder* easy to use. (like the way it should be). check it out.

Answer (score 19):

#### iOS 15 and above

You can pass in a customized Text as the label ('aka' placeholder):

```
TextField(text: $text) {
    Text("Placeholder").foregroundColor(.red)
}
```

---

#### iOS 14 and below

You can build a custom placeholder with a few lines of code like this:

Use `ZStack` and implement a placeholder yourself:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
        if text.isEmpty {
            Text("Placeholder")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
        TextField("", text: $text)
    }
}
```

So you can do **any** customization you like to the *placeholder*.

---

#### Custom TextField (with placeholder)

You can always create your own custom `View`s to use everywhere:

```
struct CustomTextField: View {
    var placeholder: Text
    @Binding var text: String
    var editingChanged: (Bool)->() = { _ in }
    var commit: ()->() = { }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if text.isEmpty { placeholder }
            TextField("", text: $text, onEditingChanged: editingChanged, onCommit: commit)
        }
    }
}
```

usage **(`TextField` with placeholder)**:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        CustomTextField(
            placeholder: Text("placeholder").foregroundColor(.red),
            text: $text
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'v do it exactly that. I hoped that there is right way do it with TextField only

Comment: How are you disable clickable for ZStack? I can't click by TextField, where is a hint.